# How can I save the result of a function in a variable in BASH?

Tags: bash, function

it's my first question. I just want to know how could I save the result of the function 'square' into the variable 'sqr':

```
!/bin/bash

function square()
{
    let y=$x*$x
    return $y
}

x=3
**sqr=square**
echo "The square of $x is $sqr"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The functions in bash are really procedures (it does not return anything). Therefore you have two options: Save in a goblal variable the result, or save the output:

```
function myfunc(){
    myresult='anything'
}

myfunc
echo $myresult
```

or

```
function myfunc(){
    local   myresult='anything'
    echo "$myresult"
}

result=$(myfunc)
echo $result
```

Comment: Ok, # or result=`myfunc` dont work